# How Do I Prevent This Rate Limiter Error on Geopy?

Tags: python, pandas, geolocation, geopy

I have a dataframe full of postcodes from the UK. I have around 400 rows and want to get the Geocode of these postcodes so I can plot them at a later date. I've used the following guide so not sure what quite is causing the error either:

https://practicaldatascience.co.uk/data-science/how-to-geocode-and-map-addresses-in-geopy

I have got the following code. The dataframe I am using is just a 1 column long dataframe with UK postcodes from a dummy dataset.

```
import pandas as pd

import folium

import geopy
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from geopy.extra.rate_limiter import RateLimiter

geocoder = RateLimiter(Nominatim(user_agent='Get_Lat_Longs').geocode, min_delay_seconds=1)

df = pd.read_excel('Postcodes.xls', sheet_name='Addresses formatted')

df_copy = df.copy()

df_postcodes = df_copy['Postcode'].to_frame()
df_postcodes['Geocode'] = df_postcodes['Postcode'].apply(geocoder)
```

However, I get the following error and I'm not quite sure how to go about debugging what I have done, any help would be appreciated.

```
RateLimiter caught an error, retrying (0/2 tries). Called with (*('N20 0PE',), **{}).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\np\env\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 696, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "c:\users\np\env\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 964, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "c:\users\np\env\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 364, in connect
    conn = self._connect_tls_proxy(hostname, conn)
  File "c:\users\np\env\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 507, in _connect_tls_proxy
    ssl_context=ssl_context,
  File "c:\users\np\env\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 453, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls)
  File "c:\users\np\env\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 495, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 423, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 870, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 1139, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
socket.timeout: _ssl.c:1074: The handshake operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\np\env\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "c:\users\np\env\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 796, in urlopen
    **response_kw
  File "c:\users\np\env\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 796, in urlopen
    **response_kw
  File "c:\users\np\env\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 756, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "c:\users\np\env\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 574, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='nominatim.openstreetmap.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /search?q=N20+0PE&format=json&limit=1 (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', timeout('_ssl.c:1074: The handshake operation timed out')))
```

Comment: problem is not `rate limit` but `The handshake operation timed out` and `ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.` - it couldn't connect with server so it tried it again and again - but problem is wrong connection. Maybe it was only temporary problem with server, or maybe you have to update `OpenSSL`, or maybe you use Proxy Server and you should skip it because it doesn't work.

Comment: if I run `geocoder('Buckingham Palace, London, SW1 1AA')` then it works without error but gives `None`. If I run `geocoder('a')` then I get `error` - it seems server has problem when data make no sense. I see your code try to search `N20+0PE` (in your error `Max retries exceeded with url: /search?q=N20+0PE`) and maybe this makes all problem. Maybe you should run it in `try/except` to catch error.

Comment: I've ran a try except block and had no luck still. I'm running this on a virtual machine so could that be the issue? However, it shouldn't be giving None should it? The example showed that it should work?

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see for what value it makes problem. And next try this value directly on web page to see if it can give result. In virtual machine you can also use web browser (if you run it with GUI) to test if you have connection with internet, or you can try in console `ping www.somepage.com` to check if it can connect with this page. You could also check if you get `None` for `geocoder('Buckingham Palace, London, SW1 1AA')` - it could confirm that it has connection.

Comment: So with the postcode, when I type it in manually on the website, it's able to find the location just fine? That's why I'm not sure if it's the issue. It's weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I was trying to do this within a virtual machine. After checking the comments given, I was able to determine that inside the virtual machine, the request wasn't being sent to the website, however on my local machine, this wasn't the issue and I was able to get the geocodes of everything.